# converting an if statement to a switch statement

Tags: if-statement, case, switch-statement

How can I convert the following if=statement to a switch-statement WITHOUT needing to create a case for every number between that interval (41-49)? Is it possible?

```
if (num < 50 && num > 40)
{
    printf("correct!");
}
```

Comment: In what language? C? C++? Something else?

Comment: And _why_ would you want to convert such an expression?

Answer (score 1):

You have to enumerate every case for a switch. The compiler converts this to a jump table, so you can't use ranges. You can, however, have multiple cases use the same block of code, which may be closer to what you want.

```
switch(num) {
    case 41:
    case 42:
    case 43:
    case 44:
    case 45:
    case 46:
    case 47:
    case 48:
    case 49:
        printf("correct!");
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
switch ((num-41)/9) {
case 0:
    printf("correct!");
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
bool criteria1 = (num < 50 && num > 40);
switch criteria1: ...
```

It may result in multilevel decision networks.. scary?

Comment: are booleans the only way to do this? is there another method? can i attach conditions to the case instead? just curious.

Comment: @wadafarfar, if your desired language supports returning true|false values when evaluating (...) and they are seen by switch statement - then, yes. `switch (condition) true: code1; false: code2; end;` will work. Write a test for that?

Answer (score 0):

In C or C++ (since you are using printf, I'll assume that's what it is), cases need to be enumerated for each choice.

The only difference between `switch/case` and `if` is the possibility that the compiler can turn it into a computed goto instead of checking ranges. If `switch/case` supported ranges, that would defeat the purpose of opening the possibility of this optimizaton.